# Стоит ли передавать по ссылке объект, используя при этом конcтантный метод?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Часто в книгах встречал конструкцию вида:

void add_foo(const Foo&) const;

В книге объясняют тем, что лучше использовать константные методы, чтобы сразу было видно, где что меняется, а где нет.

Стоит ли передавать по ссылке объект, используя при этом конcтантный метод? Или следует лучше просто передавать без ссылки и без const?
Кроме как нежелание копировать большой объект в память не могу придумать причин использовать так "извращенно" передачу по ссылке. По сути мы берем инструмент для передачи с возможностью изменения исходного объекта и запрещаем это делать. Стоит ли так делать постоянно? Может есть какие-то более важные причины о которых я просто не знаю?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно всегда помнить про два аспекта восприятия Вашего кода - компилятором и следующим программистом.

С точки зрения компилятора и среды, держать в голове оптимизацию. Несмотря на гигабайты и мегагерцы ), а вдруг как Вас завтра кинет в embedded.

Но гораздо важнее помнить о читателях Вашего кода!
void add_foo(const Foo& foo) четко сообщает о том, что add_foo никак не поменяет состояние объекта foo и будет пользоваться только const методами класса Foo.
Так же и указание метода как const, говорит о неизменности состояния объектов класса после вызова.

> Стоит ли передавать по ссылке объект, используя при этом конcтантный метод?

Всегда, когда возможно )

> Или следует лучше просто передавать без ссылки и без const?

На практике, крайне редко можно встретить передачу копии объекта, исключая POD типы. А, например, для класса использующего ресурсы (SomeFile) так и просто чревато.

> По сути мы берем инструмент для передачи с возможностью изменения исходного объекта и запрещаем это делать.

RTFM
http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references

P.S. Почему я упомянул про среду
Например в Qt широко используется ленивое копирование, и потому практической разницы в передачи копии или ссылки - мало. Но, опять же, помним про читателя.

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ. Начал использовать везде указание const при передаче по ссылке. В итоге через пару задач VS 2013 стал в предупреждениях выдавать такое.    anachronism used : qualifiers on reference are ignored. На такой код. 'Foo nameFunction(Foo& const Foo1)' Вот комментарии самих MS по этому поводу. [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba028dad-c21f-4b0c-bf31-2195b9431410/warning-c4227-anachronism-used-qualifiers-on-reference-are-ignored-edit-topicmark-as?forum=vcgeneral]. Получается так лучше не делать? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ответ вы практически нашли сами. Он последний по приведенной

Comment: Уппс...
Вы нашли его сами. Посмотрите внимательно на последний ответ по приведенной Вами ссылке.
И, для закрепления, сюда (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense). Поскольку Вы, как мне показалось, ищущий программист, рекомендую плотно изучить FAQ на этом сайте.

Comment: @denis-savenko. И, на всякий случай, явный ответ.
const Type& ref - ссылка на неизменный объект типа. Type& const object - неизменная ссылка на объект типа. Это суть разные вещи, и второй не имеет смысла исходя из природы ссылок.
В то время, как const Type* const pointer - вполне себе нормальная конструкция )

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь более или менее понятно. Надо еще на паре примеров будет разобраться, чтобы понять. Спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правы.

Передача по константной ссылке практически (при правильном программировании) ничем не отличается от передачи копии. Причина обычно состоит лишь в оптимизации ненужного копирования.

---

Окей, существует случай, когда и правда есть разница. Например, если вы хотите сохранить ссылку на объект и следить за ним, вызывая методы-геттеры. При этом если объект передан по const-ссылке, вы будете реально видеть изменения переданного объекта. Если же вам передана копия, вы будете видеть лишь изменения копии. Как мы знаем, `const` означает лишь read-only view на объект, но не означает, что объект *сам* не может поменяться.

---

Тем не менее, в большинстве случаев имеется в виду одно и то же, и передача делается по const-ссылке лишь для оптимизации.

---

А `const` («для того, чтобы случайно не поменять») можно использовать и при передаче по значению, да.

Comment: Спасибо, объяснение про отслеживание изменения самого объекта мне кажется достаточно веской причиной чтобы писать так) Буду так и делать тогда...

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, вы путаете константные методы класса и константные ссылки-параметры.
Константный метод не изменяет состояние экземпляра своего класса, а не переданных параметров.

Comment: Да. Но когда идет сложение двух объектов, без использование перегруженного + в книжке пишут, мол лучше делать константным и ссылку-параметр, я так понимаю чтобы в самом методе не изменить другой объект. Хотелось понять почему так, а не передать копию.